# voiceChannel.join() isn't a function node v16 discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a bot that plays music. I upgraded to NodeJS v16.6.1 and voiceChannel.join doesn't work anymore.
I already tried using `const { voiceChannel } = require('@discord.js/voice');` but it just says module not found.
Code:

````
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const ytSearch = require("yt-search");

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the neccesary permissions');
        if (!permissions.has("SPEAK")) return message.channel.send('You dont have the neccesary permissions');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('Define Video');
        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
        }
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join('  '));
        if (video) {
            const stream = ytdl(video.url, {
                filter: 'audioonly'
            });
            connection.play(stream, {
                    seek: 0,
                    volume: 1
                })
                .on('finish', () => {
                    voiceChannel.leave();
                });
            await message.reply(`Now Playing **${video.title}**`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('No videos found');
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `voiceChannel#join` is not, in fact, a function. While it did exist on Discord.js v12, which I assume you were using before updating your Node.js version, note that it is nowhere to be found in [the Discord.js v13 documentation on `VoiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel). Instead, you are to migrate to [`@discordjs/voice`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/voice), whose [`joinVoiceChannel`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/modules.html#joinvoicechannel) function can be used as a replacement.

Comment: Still says```Error: Cannot find module '@discordjs/voice'```

Comment: You need to install it via your package manager of choice.

Comment: Installed it with ```npm install discordjs/voice```
but still says ```Error: Cannot find module '@discordjs/voice'```

Comment: Note the difference between **`@`**`discordjs/voice` and `discordjs/voice`.

Comment: Tried both '@discordjs/voice' and 'discordjs/voice'